# 2005 Hoda Civic VP Turns Over and almost starts but immediately dies

Tags: honda, civic, stall

My sons 2005 Honda Civic VP has about 160000 miles on it has never had any issues. He was driving and it just died. Car turns over strong attemps to start but immediately dies. It does have gas in it.

Comment: Welcome to Motor Vehicle Maintenance & Repair!

Comment: It will start every time and then quits? It looks as though you didn't finish your question before you posted it. Was there other information you didn't provide? If so, please edit your question and add it.

Comment: Do you have any means of checking the fuel pump pressure? Sounds like it might be giving enough to get it started, but then not putting out anything after that.